# How can I direct text inputs to a hidden field in a html page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to handle copying and pasting to an application I'm developing by redirecting them into a hidden field. The problem is that, when I set `visibility: hidden` on the field I'm trying to direct the input to, typing or copy/pasting into the field doesn't seem to work. I'm trying to use a `<textarea>` tag to catch the text, and setting the focus with `document.select('textAreaID').focus()`, and it works, unless I set `visibility: hidden` in the css.

[Test fiddle that shows that behavior. Blue square gives focus, red and green toggle visibility.](http://jsfiddle.net/4Jwxv/1/)

Is there a good way to hide the text area and still be able to paste or type into it? If not, is there a good alternate way to redirect copy behavior to yield a chunk of text that can be parsed, edited, and worked with?

(Also: there's some d3 in the fiddle since I'm using it for something else and it offers convenient APIs.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like browsers do not allow focusing on visibility:hidden elements. It might be different on other browsers, but it wasn't working for me on Chrome:
http://jsfiddle.net/ps6KK/

So since we can't do visibility:hidden we need to essentially force the textarea to seem like it's hidden. You can do that by wiping out all of it's height/weight/etc and setting the background to transparent. You might also want to set the text color to transparent if you want.

```
#textDiv {
  resize: none;
  padding: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 0;
  width: 0;
  background: transparent;
}
```

A more detailed example is here:
http://jsfiddle.net/4Jwxv/1/

Comment: Forgot about resize:none :)

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use the .html() method in jQuery to update the textarea

Comment: I don't need to update the text area, I need to be able to direct inputs to it. I'm trying to catch some text being pasted on a ctrl+v without messing with the clipboard directly, and want it to paste into a hidden text area.

Comment: Correct, so use a jQuery event handler to capture the pasted value, and the .html() method to assign that value to the textarea

Comment: That would require that I paste the data somewhere else in the document, at which point I wouldn't need to paste it into the text area, since the text area is just a convenient place to catch the data for processing.

Answer (score 0):

Is it your problem storing the text when you "copy" (not "paste") it? You can do that with a good old global JavaScript variable (not declared inside the event handler function, but outside); no need to store it into a hidden HTML element.